# How android View.setBackground() works?

Tags: android, setbackground

I am facing a problem. In a activity i have two linear layout.First one's height is 300dp  and second one's height is  150dp. I create a BitmapDrawable from  1024 X 615 resource image. But the problem is when i use the  BitmapDrawable as background by setBackground() method the BitmapDrawable show same length in both layout, where first layout background image length should double from the second. There is some space between layout but image length is same.

Here is xml code .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/rel1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
    >

        </LinearLayout>

<TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Divider"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/ln2"
    >

</LinearLayout>
```

Code in onCreate()

```
    Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.section_background);
    BitmapDrawable backGroundBitmap = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), background);
    BitmapDrawable backGroundBitmap2 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), background);
    findViewById(R.id.ln2).setBackground(backGroundBitmap);
    findViewById(R.id.rel1).setBackground(backGroundBitmap);
```

This is the screenshot of output: [image: output]

This is expected output:[image: expected]

If i declare the background resource in xml the output is as expected. And if i use "backGroundBitmap" and "backGroundBitmap2" separately in  2 layout the output is as expected.

```
  findViewById(R.id.ln2).setBackground(backGroundBitmap);
  findViewById(R.id.rel1).setBackground(backGroundBitmap2);
```

Anyone please can explain why this happen . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use a [NinePatchDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html), so that it will adjust it's size to fit the view. To quote the documentation:

```
NinePatchDrawable
=================

A resizeable bitmap, with stretchable areas that you define.
This type of image is defined in a .png file with a special format.
```

Visit [Draw-9 Patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for more specific information on how to create the images.